# Retrofit 2.1.0 GsonConverterFactory.create()

Tags: android, retrofit

I have read all the posts on Retrofit , but still i haven't got the solution why `GsonConverterFactory.create()` has an error , i have `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'` and `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'` but still the error is still visisble on the top below is the Image 
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , i have got a simpler way of doing this, i have placed 2 libs **convert-gson-2.0.1.jar** and **retrofit2.0.1** in the libs folder and i synced . Then this will be working perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

In your build.gradle file add

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
```

be sure to use the same version of both

**EDIT:**

In your top gradle file , which is build.gradle (module project) , add `jcenter()`  . So your top gradle file should look like this

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
   // please use the build tool version you are using right now 
   // it might be different 
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added them in the gradle , but still its not importing(not working) , let me ask should i leave my Retrofit v2.1.0jar in the libs folder  @shuvro

Comment: sure , remove jar from lib folder , then it should work

Comment: i have removed it , but there;s an error `failed to resolve com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4` and `failed to resolve com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4`

Comment: Why not use 2.1.0 instead of 2.0.0 beta 4?